# Jenkins Workflow Plugin: How to create a job from groovy DSL?

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, dsl, jenkins-workflow

I'm evaluating https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workflow+Plugin and very like its concept of Groovy DSL in Jenkinsfile under version control. I tried to create different build steps, nodes and stages.

I have a multi-module project and want to have a kind of separate "job" for each module. Each module should have it's own Junit, Findbugs, Checkstyle reports.

However when I tried to collect Junit report it was attached to Workflow job, not it's node or stage.

**Question:**

Is it possible to create (and update dynamically) a job from Jenkins Workflow plugin DSL? If not, is there any analogue of job that can handle several reports within single workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Workflow flow scripts can access the Jenkins model I suspect they *can* update a job configuration (is that what you mean by the first question?), but don't know if that's its strong suit. That would be a task for [Job DSL plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin).

[Build steps can invoke other jobs](https://dzone.com/refcardz/continuous-delivery-with-jenkins-workflow)--search for **build job** in that page--and each of those can have its own publish steps. That might get what you need.

Comment: Not to mention the generic **step** build step, which might help if you want a "flat" workflow--all steps coded in the flow script itself instead of in subordinate jobs.

Comment: Brian, Job DSL plugin is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can also run downstream jobs from Workflow, using the `build` step.

Answer (score 0):

[JENKINS-27395](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27395) (and analogues for other publishers) would be needed to fully support this use case in one Workflow job. Currently reports from different parts of the build are simply aggregated.